# How attach \circ to each horizontal labels representing angles?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

The objective is to attach `\circ` to each horizontal labels representing angles in degrees. How to do so? I cannot find the solution in the `pst-plot` manual.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\dx{pi/4}
\FPeval\Dx{round(180/pi*dx:0)}
\FPeval\dy{1}


\FPeval\XMin{0-pi/3}
\FPeval\XMax{2*pi}
\FPeval\YMin{0-3}
\FPeval\YMax{3}


\FPeval\L{XMin-dx/2}
\FPeval\R{XMax+dx/2}
\FPeval\B{YMin-dy/2}
\FPeval\T{YMax+dy/2}


\psset
{
    algebraic,
    xunit=15mm,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\L,\B)(\R,\T)
    \psaxes[dx=\dx,Dx=\Dx]{->}(0,0)(\L,\B)(\R,\T)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{\XMin}{\XMax}{2*sin(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Change to Tikz, and use `pgfplots` instead, it's more robust and versatile. (Before, I used `pstricks`, but now i don't change `Tikz`)

Comment: @skpblack, if this particular OP does that, I believe the Earth might stop turning... ;-)

Comment: @skpblack: robustness and versatility cannot be judged without reliable data gathered via scientific researches. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 \psaxes[dx=\dx,Dx=\Dx,xlabelFactor={}^\circ]{->}(0,0)(\L,\B)(\R,\T)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun with `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  x={1.5cm/60},
  domain=-60:360,
  samples=100,
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=center,
  xmin=-70, xmax=370,
  xtick={-45,45,90,...,360},
  xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber\tick^{\circ}$},
  ymin=-3.5, ymax=3.5,
  ytick={-3,-2,-1,1,2,3},
]
  \addplot[blue,mark=none] {2*sin x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you are firing @cyanide-based food's own bullets at him! Sweet revenge ;-) Very good.

Comment: @HarishKumar of course, giving a taste of his own medicine. ;-) :-)